# How to read properties of node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I am quite new to `neo4j`, and constructing **db** which consists of **>10M** nodes. During query operations I want to find a node by using two `properties` of it. For example: node - `name: xxx surname: yyy id:1` during query operation I need to get node `id` which `name: xxx, surname: yyy`. How is it possible with java query (not cypher)? And there will be more than one entry with given properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to find ids:

```
GraphDatabaseService database;

Label label = DynamicLabel.label("your_label_name");
String propertyId = "id";
String propertyName = "name";
String propertySurname = "surname";

public Set<Node> getIdsForPeople(Set<Person> people) {

    Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

    try(Transaction tx = database.beginTx()) {
        for (Person person in people) {
            Node node = database.findNode(label, propertyName, person.getName());

            if (node.hasProperty(propertySurname)) {
                if (node.getProperty(propertySurname) == person.getSurname()) {
                    String id = node.getProperty(propertyId).toString();

                    ids.add(id);
                }
            }
        }

        tx.success();
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Person holder

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getSurname() { return surname; }
}
```

example

```
Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>(){{
    add(new Person("xxx1", "yyy1"));
    add(new Person("xxx2", "yyy2"));
    add(new Person("xxx3", "yyy3");
    add(new Person("xxx4", "yyy4");
}};

Set<String> ids = getIdsForPeople(people);
```

Comment: if there is more than one entry with given specifications what should I do?